# How to deserialize objects with dynamic name

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm want to deserialize the below JSON response into a Java object.

But the name of field **Time Series** is dynamic for e.g. it can be `Time Series (5min)`, `Time Series (1min)`, `Time Series (15min)` etc.

Is there any annotation or configuration that can help in deserializing the JSON into POJO irrespective of field name?

JSON Response:

```
{
  "Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
    "2. Symbol": "IBM",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-10-09 19:55:00",
    "4. Interval": "5min",
    "5. Output Size": "Compact",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (5min)": {
    "2020-10-09 19:55:00": {
      "1. open": "127.7500",
      "2. high": "127.7500",
      "3. low": "127.7000",
      "4. close": "127.7000",
      "5. volume": "405"
    },
    "2020-10-09 19:45:00": {
      "1. open": "127.7600",
      "2. high": "127.7600",
      "3. low": "127.7600",
      "4. close": "127.7600",
      "5. volume": "200"
    }
  }
}
```

POJO for JSON response:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class IntraDayResponse {

    @JsonProperty("Meta Data")
    private Metadata metadata;

    private Map<String, IntraDayData> timeSeries;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved by creating a setter method with `String` key and `Object` value as argument and annotating it with `@JsonAnySetter`.

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class IntraDayResponse {

    @JsonProperty("Meta Data")
    private Metadata metadata;

    private Map<String, IntraDayData> timeSeries = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setTimeSeries(String key, Object value) {
        this.timeSeries = (Map<String, IntraDayData>) value;
    }
}
```

String key would have values like: `"Time Series (5min)", "Time Series (1min)", "Time Series (15min)"`
Object value will have the content.

Answer (score 0):

Since metadata already contains the information about the interval, you could utilise [JsonAlias](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) -  something like this.

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class IntraDayResponse {

    @JsonProperty("Meta Data")
    private Metadata metadata;
    @JsonAlias({ "Time Series (5min)", "Time Series (1min)", "Time Series (15min)" })
    private Map<String, IntraDayData> timeSeries;

}
```

Comment: For the explanation purpose I gave 3 values. In reality, timeseries is not limited to these 3 values, it can be any `"Time Series (XYZmin)"` I guess every possible name can't be given in JsonAlias. Can you elaborate how can we use Metadata?

Comment: Metadata has interval field which can tell about the duration. Also, you are correct. You can limit the values to 3 values. In this scenario, you could use a custom deserializer to accommodate a wildcard field name. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [@JsonAnySetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html) is suitable for this. Basically, the annotated field (support on field from version 2.8, as mentioned in doc) is then used as a default to deserialize unknown properties. Please try this.

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class IntraDayResponse {

    @JsonProperty("Meta Data")
    private Metadata metadata;

    @JsonAnySetter
    private Map<String, IntraDayData> timeSeries;

}
```

Comment: Annotating @JsonAnySetter on field isn't solving the problem, still getting same response. But, thanks for suggesting it, I figured out the answer.